# Evans Partial Differential Equations chapter 7 exercise 10 (uniqueness of regular solutions to the telegraph equation)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I would like to know how to solve exercise $10$ of chapter 7 of Evans' Partial Differential Equations, second edition. The problem goes like this:

> Suppose $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open and bounded set with smooth boundary, and $T>0$. Show there exists at most one smooth solution of this initial/boundary-value problem for the *telegraph equation*
> $$\begin{cases}
> u_{tt}+du_t-u_{xx}=f&\text{ in }(0,1)\times(0,T)\\
> u=0&\text{ on }(\{0\}\times[0,T])\cup(\{1\}\times[0,T])\\
> u=g,u_t=h&\text{ on }[0,1]\times\{t=0\}
> \end{cases}$$

I have no idea of what shall I do... if we suppose $u$ and $v$ are regular solutions of the given problem, then $u-v$ is a regular solution to the following problem
$$\begin{cases}
u_{tt}+du_t-u_{xx}=0&\text{ in }(0,1)\times(0,T)\\
u=0&\text{ on }(\{0\}\times[0,T])\cup(\{1\}\times[0,T])\\
u=0,u_t=0&\text{ on }[0,1]\times\{t=0\}
\end{cases}$$
However, I don't know how to prove that any regular solution to the last problem must be identically zero in $(0,1)\times(0,T)$... I think the best way to proceed would be to make some change of variables in order to get rid of the term in $u_t$ above, and get some hyperbollic problem.

I am completely lost, so any help will be appreciated.